# How to manage sidebar menu in navigation between pages in JSF?

Tags: jsf, navigation, submenu

I'm using a custom template with a sidebar: i have 3 grouped menu that can be opened or closed. I would open a menu only when I'm on certain pages.

I tried to use a NavigationController with a property that let me understand "where" are we now so i can open the right menu.

```
@ManagedBean(eager = true)
@RequestScoped
public class NavigationController implements Serializable {
   @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.pageId}")
   private String pageId;

   public String showPage() {
       switch(pageId) {
          case "1": return "home";
          case "21": return "cerca_a";
          case "22": return "anagrafica?id_p=new&faces-redirect=true";
          ...
         default: return "home";
       }
  }
  //getter and setter
}
```

Used in sideBar.xhtml like this

```
<ul class="collapse list-unstyled #{navigationController.pageId lt 30? 'show':''}">
  <li><h:commandLink action="#{navigationController.showPage}" value="Cerca">
    <f:param name="pageId" value="31"/></h:commandLink></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

It doesn't work when I use links with params (case 22): no menu is opened, it looses #{navigationController.pageId}.
Pretty sure it happens because it is **@RequestScoped** and when i call anagrafica?id_p=new the AnagConverter is executed.

Should I use a **@ViewScoped**? How? Is there a better way to mantain a custom "breadcrumb"?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So you don't understand what `&faces-redirect=true` actually does? Remove that part and it'll work. If you want to keep it in then you'll have to add `&pageId=22` there as well.

Comment: Hi @BalusC: maybe not enough..! If I don't use '&faces-redirect=true' then menu works but param 'id_p=new' is not seen by anagrafica.xhtml (that, in that case, build a page for new item). If I add '&pageId=22' it works but it is shown in browser url. I suppose there is not a _cleaner_ solution. Thank you!

Comment: Surely there's a cleaner solution. Just don't use page IDs but use page names/urls/paths.

Comment: Understood: I'm studying :-) Thanks a lot!